# Почему переносится текст на другую строку?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Есть **Discord-бот**. Каждый раз, когда код ловит определённый текст через регулярку, бот пишет сообщение в чат.

```
pkill = '.*? (\\w+):(\\w+)\\b(?!:)'

with open(file, encoding='utf-8', mode='rt') as b:
    b.seek(0,2)
    while True:
        k = b.readline()

        if(re.search(pkill, k)):
            names = k[12:].split(":")
            player, attacker = names[0], names[1]
            await kchannel.send(':crossed_swords: Игрок **' + attacker + '** убил игрока **'+ player +'**')
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
```

---

На тестовом боте выходит одно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На другом боте *(основном)* совсем другое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну сделайте `attacker.strip() `

Comment: @КириллМалышев, а что он ещё делает, кроме как убирает символы? Ну, вот в данном моменте.

Comment: Почитайте документацию. Без аргументов эта функция удаляет пробельные символы в начале и в конце строки.

Comment: `readline()` возвращает строку вместе с символом переноса строки в конце. Т.к., Вы забираете значения, используя `split(':')`, то в `names[1]` попадает строка вместе с переносом.